# When decreasing the y-axis range, my bar and the label overlap

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to decrease the y-axis range to observe the pattern of the my barplot, but when I decrease the range, the label and the bar overlap...

[image]

Below is my code:

```
> head(employed)
> Years <- seq(2007,2021,1)
> barplot(employed$Numbers,names.arg=Years, 
  ylim= range(pretty(c(5000,15000))), 
  xlab = "Year",ylab = "Numbers",main="Number of Employment",las=2)
> head(employed)
  Year Numbers
1 2007 10538.1
2 2008 10659.6
3 2009 10897.3
4 2010 11899.5
5 2011 12351.5
6 2012 12820.5
```

Can someone help me to 'erase' the bar below the x-axis and to increase the distance between the ylab and the range?

Comment: Hello.  Could you please include a minimal data set (or use one of the built-in ones) and the code you used to produce your plot?  The answer may be very different with base `R` or with `ggplot2` for example.

Comment: Hi and welcome Hong Xuan! This certainly seems like this is something contributors here could help with, but you will likely get better, faster help if you edit your question to make this reproducible - including code to recreate your data (ie, `dput(your_date)`) and any code you have used to make the barplot in the figure. For some tips on improving your question, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: (Hong Xuan ... if you don't respond to these requests relatively quickly, your question is likely to be closed as "not reproducible" or "needs details". Please, when you ask a question on SO, it is very good to be responsive quickly, otherwise questions are often closed fairly quickly. I don't like it that way, but it is what happens. Good luck!)